# How to calculate R-squared for the unequal number of LST and CO samples?

Tags: regression, r-squared, generalized-estimating-equations

I want to calculate R-squared from LST and CO data in GEE. However, after considering the revisit time and cloud masking, I get very few data for Landsat-8 with respect to CO data. For example I have 15 LST samples for the specific months. In return, I have almost 70 samples for CO data. Since the total number of LST and CO data are not equal, I cannot compute an R-squared value. How can I handle this? Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.